# Boost Iostreams component() call fails

Tags: c++, boost, iostream

I'm trying to access the underlying `std::ifstream` added to a `boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf` chain. According to the [FAQ](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/faq.html#component_access), one way to do this is by using `component/component_type`. Why does the below code fail?

```
std::ifstream fp{"input.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary};
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::counter{});
in.push(fp);
auto *c = in.component<boost::iostreams::counter>(0); // works
std::cout << (c == nullptr) << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << c->characters() << std::endl;
std::cout << c->lines() << std::endl;

// Look into ifstream
auto *f_ptr = in.component<std::ifstream>(1); // fails
std::cout << (f_ptr == nullptr) << std::endl; // 1
```

[Run on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbf2b2d3d2c343c9)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: &fp Im assuming, basically it shouldnt be nullptr.